# Combining rectangle/square areas into bigger ones - imshow/python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, wxwidgets

I have been stuck on this problem for the past two weeks, trying to find a way of combining a set of rectangles/squares into a bigger one that would encompass areas of interest. The work is done in Python.

I am working on a instrument that acquires intensity information in X- and Y- direction of any surface. I can carry out my experiments in array of resolution, but as expected higher resolution increases the time frame of the experiment significantly. My aim is to do the experiment in low resolution which would then be followed by higher resolution experiment but only in areas where there is something interesting. I've attached an image to show you what I mean.

[image]

I am not particularly interested in anything other than yellow/orange spots. So I am extracting the areas of certain intensity that correspond to my minimal threshold. I end up with XY-centres that I expand to rectangle/square size. I would like the image below to have 5 areas of interest, that would encompass minimal area around the hotspots.

Unfortunately, what I end up having is this ( a total of 53 rectangles to represent 5 areas):
[image]

The problem is in the number of rectangles - it is purely based on the intensity of the peaks. I would like to reduce it from 53 to 5 by either 1) combining overlapping rectangles into one big rectangle OR 2) keeping only a single rectangle that represents the others.

Thus far, I've tried many different ways of looking at it, but I cannot get it to work. I've explored the `wx` module where I can check if rectangles overlap, checked if points are found close to one another, if centre points are inside other rectangles, etc etc...

I intentionally didn't post any code, since none of it works particularly well...

If any of you could help with this, I would be eternally grateful!

**UPDATE 1**
Thanks to Kenney, I've got a working code that does what I would like to it do. I have so far tested it only on one set of results, but will update again once I analyse more. Have a look at the resultant image.

[image]

Comment: Testing for overlapping rectangles looks like the way to go: if you add a second rectangle that overlaps with a pre-existing first one, you can expand the boundaries of the first one and discard the second. If you do it like that, you should end up with 5 rectangles.

Comment: @Kenney Do you know what would be the best way to do it? I've tried that but I still end up with incorrect number of rectangles..

Comment: There's no guarantee that the rectangles won't overlap, but I'd adjust the existing rectangle with the minimum top/left and maximum bottom/right coordinates. You might have to pick the rectangle with the largest overlapping area if there are multiple matches. Or, check if the center of the new rectangle is inside an existing one. I'd be interested to see your attempt and the result you got?

Comment: I noticed that in your output, even though you have 53 rectangles (seems like less), they are clustered into five groups that do not overlap. You could post-process those rectangles to group them, and then average their bounds.

Comment: 1) I am working on a version of the a code that does what you suggested.    2) The image does have all 53 rectangles, the differences in XY positions can be quite small. I agree, the 5 areas are represented well, so if I could cluster them together and then take average  of them it would work. I am just not sure how I can group them together, sorting them by X or Y or XY  does not work.

Comment: You should look into `shapely`  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely which does computational geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that post-processes the rectangles to cluster them.
I took some utility code from [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31352/overlapping-rectangles) since I'm completely new to python:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Rect(object):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        '''Store the top, bottom, left and right values for points 
               p1 and p2 are the (corners) in either order
        '''
        self.left   = min(p1.x, p2.x)
        self.right  = max(p1.x, p2.x)
        self.bottom = min(p1.y, p2.y)
        self.top    = max(p1.y, p2.y)

    def __str__(self):
         return "Rect[%d, %d, %d, %d]" % ( self.left, self.top, self.right, self.bottom )

def range_overlap(a_min, a_max, b_min, b_max):
    '''Neither range is completely greater than the other
    '''
    return (a_min <= b_max) and (b_min <= a_max)

def rect_overlaps(r1,r2):
    return range_overlap(r1.left, r1.right, r2.left, r2.right) and range_overlap(r1.bottom, r1.top, r2.bottom, r2.top)
```

And here's the algorithm:

```
rectangles = [

    # A______
    # |      |
    # -------B

    #     A             B
    Rect( Point(10,10), Point(50,70)),
    Rect( Point( 8,10), Point(30,20)),
    Rect( Point(90,90), Point(99,99)),
];


clusters = [];

for rect in rectangles:
    matched = 0;
    for cluster in clusters:
        if ( rect_overlaps( rect, cluster ) ):
            matched=1
            cluster.left   = min( cluster.left,   rect.left   );
            cluster.right  = max( cluster.right,  rect.right  );
            cluster.top    = min( cluster.top,    rect.top    );
            cluster.bottom = max( cluster.bottom, rect.bottom );

    if ( not matched ):
        clusters.append( rect );

print "Clusters:"
for c in clusters:
    print c
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help... IT WORKED! You are a life saver. Thanks! See attached image to see the results.